# When running selenium tests, getting 403 error sometimes in UI (request could not satisfied. Request blocked.)

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, amazon-cloudfront

I run my test cases from jenkins and local. I have been getting 403 Error for some of my tests (not for all) in browser of late. Does anyone have solution for this?

Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner. If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Comment: 1. use a library like [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver. 2. Use a proxy, there are many providers. For example asocks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to check whether this 403 error is occurring due to more calls being hit or due to any firewall blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate limit has been increased by infra guys in AWS, it works fine now